# Question voted for close

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892257/why-sample-statistics-converge-to-the-right-parameter) of mine has been voted to be closed. The reason stated there is because some user thinks it's off topic. Is it really? In my opinion, it's not, but I maybe wrong.

What do you think?

Comment: There *is* a statistics stack exchange. Maybe that's more suitable?

Comment: It is not clear what the people who voted to close believe "off topic" to mean. It is a clear question, definitely on a serious mathematical topic.

Comment: The voter for "off topic" selected "no context" as the reason.  I initially voted with this person (becoming the 2nd close vote), because I mis-read the question to be "how should I prove a), b), c)" (because that's the format a lot of users asking homework questions use.)  Upon closer examination, I've retracted my vote. I suspect the original voter also misread the question.  I wouldn't worry about it, if I were you--quite a few close-vote reviewers have voted to "leave open."

Comment: Ok. Thanks everybody. ;)

Comment: @Andre: I do think it's pretty likely that they believe it to mean that this looks like yet another "here's my exercise, do it for me" problem. And I agree that it *does* look like such a thing if you just give it a cursory look over. (I did vote to leave open as well)

Comment: @Hurkyl Well, I wouldn't know since I'm selfstudying. But wouldn't be strange I post a HW question in almost mid August? I don't know many(or any) universities with classes in August.

Comment: @Hurkyl:  Voting to close has become fashionable, so people do it early and often, without necessarily reading.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. This is a bit off-topic, but consider summer sessions, online schools with year-round schedule, the Antipodes...

Comment: @900sit-upsaday hum... ok.

Comment: As a tangential matter, the tag `order-statistics` seems out of place on this Question.  [Order statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) have to do with ranked/sorted observations, not with "order" of moments, etc.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. MSE has participants from different countries.  In the Philippines, for example, practically all universities (for now) have a school year that starts in June and ends in March (with summer sessions from April to May).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, someone cast a close vote thinking the question lacked context. The voter was mistaken. The reviewers in the Close Review queue voted

```
Leave Open, Close, Leave Open, Leave Open
```

at which point the review completed: there were enough Leave Open votes for the question to be removed from the queue, and for the existing votes to start aging.

The second Close vote was retracted; the question is left with one vote that will age away.